# Initializing a static singleton object with NSCoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton, nskeyedarchiver, initwithcoder

I'm working on an iPhone app and facing some troubles with my shared singleton class.
I'm using a shared singleton to store two variables
`int gameRuns` and `int totalScore`
'gamRuns' just increments every time the user loads the app, and 'totalScore' is obvious :D

the issue is as follows, I load the singleton and init using my own method when the app loads using this code:

```
+ (SingletonLevelState*)sharedLevelStateInstance {

static SingletonLevelState *sharedLevelStateInstance;

@synchronized(self) {
    if(!sharedLevelStateInstance) {
        //Init a singleton
        sharedLevelStateInstance = [[SingletonLevelState alloc] init];
        sharedLevelStateInstance->gameRuns = 1;
        sharedLevelStateInstance->totalScore = 0;
    }
}
return sharedLevelStateInstance;
}
```

This is working great as I can reference this class from any other class and always get a pointer to the same object, so this works fine from other objects:

```
sharedLevelState = [SingletonLevelState sharedLevelStateInstance];
sharedLevelStateInstance.gameRuns++;
```

Now I added the NSCoder protocol, and added the two methods `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder` as follows :

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    //encode level data
    [coder encodeInt:self->gameRuns forKey:@"gameRuns"];
    [coder encodeInt:self->totalScore forKey:@"totalScore"];
}
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self->gameRuns = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"gameRuns"];
        self->totalScore = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"totalScore"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now when the app loads, I check to see if we already have a saved sate, if it exists, I just unarchive the class with that file, if not, I init that class using my custom method above, then set its defaults, encode it to file so we have a saved state, here's the code:

```
 //Load Level state
sharedLevelStateInstance = [SingletonLevelState sharedLevelStateInstance];

//Check if file is saved
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString *gameStatePath = [NSString stringWithString:[self getSavePath]];

if([fm fileExistsAtPath:gameStatePath]){
    [self loadState];
    sharedLevelStateInstance.gameRuns = sharedLevelStateInstance.gameRuns+1;
    NSLog(@"Loaded %d times", [sharedLevelStateInstance gameRuns]);
}
[fm release];
```

Now the last line in the if statement works perfectly, it increments every time I load the app as expected and *I feel really happy* lol.

*However, the problem arises* when I try to get a reference of the singleton in another class by doing the following:

```
sharedLevelStateInstance = [SingletonLevelState sharedLevelStateInstance];
NSLog(@"Played: %d times", sharedLevelStateInstance.gameRuns);
```

It always counts back to 1, I know what happens but I'm not sue what's the best way to solve it, when I `initWithCoder` the singleton, It's not returning a static object, it creates a new one, when I init my `sharedLevelStateInstance`, it calls my first custom method, initializing it to the defaults hardcoded.

So StackOverflow, can you please help me ?!

I just need to know what's the best way to get a reference to the same object without allocating a new one every time I `initWithCoder` !

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you code should probably look like this:

```
if(self = [[SingletonLevelState sharedLevelStateInstance] retain])
```

Which sets the variables of the singleton, and returns the singleton. Be sure to retain the singleton, so that when the `NSCoder` releases this instance, it doesn't fully deallocate your singleton.

Comment: Ahhh perfect, you just saved my day :)